# How to redirect all attempts to access a folder to index, but server?

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I'm creating a new web site.

The structure of this website is:

```
root
├─ .htaccess
├─ Index.php
└─ Data
   └─Logo.png
```

My index page contains:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="Data/Logo.png" alt="logo" height="42" width="42"> 
    </body>
</html>
```

And my .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.example.com/

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteEngine On 
RedirectMatch 404 ^/Data/.*$
```

My problem:

If in .htaccess file i set `RedirectMatch 404 ^/Data/.*$` , then no visitor is able to access `example.com/Data/Logo.png` , but `index.php` can't show the image.

If in .htaccess file i set `RedirectMatch 404 ^/Data/?$` , then `Index.php` is able to show the image, but any visitor can access to `example.com/Data/Logo.png`

I want `/Data` to store images, php functions, styles and every other class.

My question:

How must i configure `htaccess` file to deny access to all visitors, but allow `Index.php` (and any other page in the website) to acces that folder?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Look at it from this perspective: you _published_ the contents of the ``Data`` folder, makes sense, since you want for example use the images in there in your application. So you grant access to those files. Now suddenly you say "yeah, I published that, but actually I do _not_ really want clients to be able to access that stuff". That does not make sense. Why should it be relevant _how_ the client accesses that image? What is so unbelievable important in taht image that you need to keep it back, although you want to publish it?

Comment: The only approach to implement what you want, apart from a decent session management, is to rely on the `HTTP_REFERER` http header sent by the clients. This however is not reliable (robust) at all, since it is trivial to get around that limitation then, http headers can be change how ever the client wants to without you on the server side being able to realize that. So the effort for such a "protection" is more than questionable.

Comment: The reason to conceal the folder is because in it is where all styles, php classes, mysql connection classes and other stuff is going to be stored. Remaking the question a little. If i make a php-mysql connection class to be referenced by another html class, is this new class "Hackable" or "Viewable"? I mean, is there a way any client could see the code in it, or is just viewable to the server?

Comment: A questionable way of reasoning. Sure, your code is accessible for clients. But as already said: that is imanent to web applications, you _want_ clients to be able to access things. If you are afraid of that then this is a symptom of a lack in confidence. Then that is what you should tackle... In general, as long as your http server is setup to interpret code and you have not implemented effort do specifically make code available there is no way a client can somehow "rip" the php code from the http server. CSS rules and JS code _can_ be retrieved, sure, but as written: that is what want!